# Could not find main class:Main, the application will exit

Tags: java

I've got Main.java, which looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("here!");
    }

}
```

I compile it with:

```
javac Main.java
```

And try to run it with

```
java Main
```

and it dies with folloving exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Main. Program will exit.
```

java -version is:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

I'm running this on Ubuntu server.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

`javac -version` is

```
javac 1.7.0_03
```

`which java`

```
/usr/bin/java
```

`which javac`

```
/usr/bin/javac
```

Comment: What's the output of `javac -version`?

Comment: What package is your Main class in? You need to give the fully qualified class name, including package name, to run the class.

Comment: it's not in package, just a class

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to *run* with Java 6, but it looks like you're *compiling* with Java 7.

Run

```
javac -version
```

to check... and assuming it shows Java 7, you need to work out *why* the two are different.

Running

```
$ which java
$ which javac
```

*might* help... the information would certainly help us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

It seems jdk you have in classpath for compilation is different from the one you have in runtime. Make sure you have same jdk available in both classpaths.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exact same problem on Ubuntu. My problem was some original libraries from openjdk-6-jre-lib needed to be completely removed. Remove that package and anything relating to openjdk 6 or jre version 6 in your synaptic manager. If you are on Ubuntu 12, you'll need to install synaptic as they removed it. I dislike using the software manager. Make sure you have version 7 installed of the open jdk.

openjdk-7-jre-lib

Keep in mind, this is the alternative to using Oracle's Java 7 install. The open means open source version.

If you install openjdk 7 on Ubuntu, the classpath should be setup automatically. I didn't have to tweak that. If you do want to tweak that, you can set it in ~/.bash_profile. But keep in mind you will have limited areas (need to be under your ~/ hierarchy) where you can compile fron the command line. And you need to reload using "drew: source .bash_profile". I tweaked classpath in /etc/environment and it messed up synaptic package manager regarding openjdk 6 on ubuntu 12. I couldn't uninstall openjdk 6 with synaptic when classpath was altered in anyway.